# Distance on a unit grid

Tags: python, performance

I have a code that calculates Euclidean distance on a grid with border crossing or without that.

```py
def distance(x1: int, y1: int, x2: int, y2: int, grid_size: int, border_cross: bool):
    if border_cross:
        min_x = min(abs(x1 - x2), grid_size - abs(x1) - abs(x2))
        min_y = min(abs(y1 - y2), grid_size - abs(y1) - abs(y2))
        return (min_x**2 + min_y**2) ** 0.5
    
    dist_x = (x1 - x2) ** 2
    dist_y = (y1 - y2) ** 2
    return (dist_x + dist_y) ** 0.5
```

Can this code be simplified or improved in terms of readability/performance?

Comment: What do you mean by "border crossing"?  And is there a good reason not to have two separate functions?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> ```py
> min_x = min(abs(x1 - x2),
> ```

> ```py
> dist_x = (x1 - x2) ** 2
> ```

We can see the border cross algorithm and the standard algorithm are similar so we can change the `if border_cross` code to mutate the values.

```py
def distance(x1: int, y1: int, x2: int, y2: int, grid_size: int, border_cross: bool):
    x = abs(x1 - x2)
    y = abs(y1 - y2)
    if border_cross:
        x = min(x, grid_size - abs(x1) - abs(x2))
        y = min(y, grid_size - abs(y1) - abs(y2))
    return (x ** 2 + y ** 2) ** 0.5
```

The code is also WET (you write the same code for x and y) so we can write a helper function to get the distance and just call the function twice.

```py
def _distance(i: int, j: int, grid_size: int, border_cross: bool) -> int:
    return (
        abs(i - j)
        if not border_cross else
        min(abs(i - j), grid_size - abs(i) - abs(j))
    )

def distance(x1: int, y1: int, x2: int, y2: int, grid_size: int, border_cross: bool) -> float:
    x = _distance(x1, x2, grid_size, border_cross)
    y = _distance(y1, y2, grid_size, border_cross)
    return (x ** 2 + y ** 2) ** 0.5
```

Personally I'd remove one of `border_cross` or `grid_size`.
By using using `None` to mean `False` and providing an integer to mean `True`.

```py
def _distance(i: int, j: int, border_cross: int | None) -> int:
    return (
        abs(i - j)
        if border_cross is None else
        min(abs(i - j), border_cross - abs(i) - abs(j))
    )

def distance(x1: int, y1: int, x2: int, y2: int, border_cross: int | None) -> float:
    x = _distance(x1, x2, border_cross)
    y = _distance(y1, y2, border_cross)
    return (x ** 2 + y ** 2) ** 0.5
```

Comment: I think it's worth noting that `(x**2 + y**2) ** 0.5` should be spelled [`math.hypot(x, y)`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/math.html#math.hypot), the latter has better numerical properties and is written in C.